# how to replace a substring of a string with a constant charecter like 'X'

Tags: c++, string, substring, character-replacement

I have a string like below

```
std::string s = "123468998";
```

I want  to replace all the character from position 0 to 4 with character 'X' 
so my string will looks like

```
"XXXXX68998"
```

is there any in build function available for this or i need to do it manually

I cant assume 1234 to be constant it may change so based on the position i want to replace

Answer (score 1):

To replace single characters in a string, you can simply access the characters in a string using `[]`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "123468998";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         s[i] = 'X';
    }
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to employ a built-in solution, you can do this:

```
s.replace(0, 5, 5, 'X');
```

Check out its documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/).

Or `std::fill`, as documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
std::fill(s.begin(), s.begin() + 5, 'X');
```

Comment: I can do it manually but i am asking is there any inbuild function available

Comment: Assuming that by inbuilt you mean part of the standard library: std::fill might be the function you are looking for: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill

Comment: Great suggestion, added the `std::fill` part.